# Google Analytics: How can we query on uploaded data (through csv files), without new incoming hits?

Tags: csv, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

**Following is the scenario:** ( I do not get any data in reports generated if no new hits arrive against the key dimension values )

> Analytics Data (collected through Google Analytics)

```
D Session ID      Page Views
S ID - 1          10
S ID - 2          20
```

**Note:** D Session ID and D Custom Data are custom dimensions, ie: in this case, **ga:dimension1 → D Session ID** and **ga:dimension2 → D Custom Data**

> Data in Uploaded CSV (Collected through some other source)

```
ga:dimension1    ga:dimension2
S ID - 1         100
S ID - 2         200
S ID - 3         300
```

Now generate report with dimensions = ga:dimension1,ga:dimension2 and metrics = ga:pageviews. This is what I observe:

1. No new hits come against S ID -1/2/3 (data present in uploaded CSV):

   ```
   No Results Found
   ```
2. Generate report after we receive new hits against S ID 1 and S ID 2:

   Generated Report (Data tables joined on ga:dimension1 or D Session ID)

   ```
   D Session ID    D Custom Data   Page Views
   S ID - 1        100             11 
   S ID - 2        200             21
   ```

Any idea, **how we can get results in case 1** ??

Comment: Basicly you want Google to return 0 if no value has been found?

Comment: No, I want it to return the data (which is present in the uploaded CSV file) if I query for "dimensions=ga:dimension1,ga:dimension2" and metric="ga:pageviews". With no new incoming matching hits. (I already have matching hit data when I uploaded the CSV file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is joining retroactively or historical import. There are 2 modes in Google Analytics for Data Import: **Processing Time** and **Query Time**.

In your scenario you're using the Processing Time mode which behaves exactly as you described, only new hits will be joined and there are also some other behaviors that are specific to Processing Time.

The behavior you're looking for is what Query Time mode provides, however this is currently only available to Google Analytics Premium accounts as described in [Query Time import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6071511).

You should review the help content, [What is Data Import?](https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/6064627) which explains all of this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't know how did I miss reading only this last link in the What is Data Import document. :)